# Receive message from channel between modules

Tags: rust, channel

I have four modules. The client is sending messages and the server is receiving messages. Once the server receives the message, it tries to send the message to the MPSC channel. I put the receiver in the other .rs file where I intend to receive the message.

I am not getting any message on the receiver side.

Maybe an infinite loop on the server side creates a problem, but is there a way to make this channel communication working?

**client.rs**

```
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::os::unix::net::UnixDatagram;
use std::path::Path;
use std::sync::mpsc;

pub fn tcp_datagram_client() {
    pub static FILE_PATH: &'static str = "/tmp/datagram.sock";
    let socket = UnixDatagram::unbound().unwrap();
    match socket.connect(FILE_PATH) {
        Ok(socket) => socket,
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Couldn't connect: {:?}", e);
            return;
        }
    };
    println!("TCP client Connected to TCP Server {:?}", socket);
    loop {
        socket
            .send(b"Hello from client to server")
            .expect("recv function failed");
    }
}

fn main() {
    tcp_datagram_client();
}
```

**server.rs**

```
use std::os::unix::net::UnixDatagram;
use std::path::Path;
use std::str::from_utf8;
use std::sync::mpsc::Sender;

fn unlink_socket(path: impl AsRef<Path>) {
    let path = path.as_ref();
    if path.exists() {
        if let Err(e) = std::fs::remove_file(path) {
            eprintln!("Couldn't remove the file: {:?}", e);
        }
    }
}

static FILE_PATH: &'static str = "/tmp/datagram.sock";
pub fn tcp_datagram_server(tx: Sender<String>) {
    unlink_socket(FILE_PATH);
    let socket = match UnixDatagram::bind(FILE_PATH) {
        Ok(socket) => socket,
        Err(e) => {
            eprintln!("Couldn't bind: {:?}", e);
            return;
        }
    };
    let mut buf = vec![0; 1024];
    println!("Waiting for client to connect...");
    loop {
        let received_bytes = socket.recv(&mut buf).expect("recv function failed");
        println!("Received {:?}", received_bytes);
        let received_message = from_utf8(&buf).expect("utf-8 convert failed");
        tx.send(received_message.to_string());
    }
}
```

**message_receiver.rs**

```
use crate::server;
use std::sync::mpsc;

pub fn handle_messages() {
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
    server::tcp_datagram_server(tx);
    let message_from_tcp_server = rx.recv().unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", message_from_tcp_server);
}
```

**main.rs**

```
mod server;
mod message_receiver;

fn main() {
    message_receiver::handle_messages();
}
```

Once the TCP client is connected:

```
TCP client Connected to TCP Server UnixDatagram { fd: 3, local: (unnamed), peer: "/tmp/datagram.sock" (pathname) }
```

I receive no messages on the channel receiver end:

```
Waiting for client to connect...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Maybe an infinite loop on the server side creates a problem

Yes, quite literally, your server code does an infinite `loop` to handle continuously messages from the client(s). So the call to `tcp_datagram_server` never returns.

> but is there a way to make this channel communication working?

Of course, it seems you are simply missing a second thread for your `message_receiver`. Wrapping your `tcp_datagram_server(tx)` in `std::thread::spawn` should do it. You could also add a `loop` to keep processing requests to match the one in `tcp_datagram_server`:

```rust
pub fn handle_messages() {
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
    std::thread::spawn(|| tcp_datagram_server(tx));
    loop {
        let message_from_tcp_server = rx.recv().unwrap();
        println!("{}", message_from_tcp_server);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you :-) @Cryptjar